# EF Core. Создание миграции по классу модели

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Есть модель:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]       
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Категория")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Есть контекст БД:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options):base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Как создать миграцию на основе класса модели? Команда Add-Migration Category создаёт только пустую миграцию.

Comment: пустую миграцию в пустой базе?

Comment: Пытаюсь реализовать СodeFirst

Answer (score 0):

Короче решение подсказали, на enSO.

Как оказалось, миграцию нужно создавать **после** добавления соответствующего `DbSet` в контекст. Тогда EF автоматически сделает всё, что нужно.

Comment: ну да, миграция же по контексту создается, нет изменений в контексте - нет миграции